# How can I sync my Opera bookmarks with Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: sync, bookmarks, opera

Is there any way to get Opera to connect to a sync service that also works in Chrome or Firefox? Because it's annoying to have to manually export Firefox bookmarks and manually import them into Opera whenever I make a change.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A quick google search reveals [BookmarkSynk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bookmarksync/) and [SiteBar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sitebar/).

Comment: Google results for Opera-supported cross-browser sync are exhausted. Neither of these services have much documentation. I can't see anywhere which browsers are supported, and BookmarkSynk's wiki is blank (literally, a blank white page).

Comment: Haven't tried either, but browsing their sites (not their wikis...), [BookmarkSync](http://www.bookmarksync.com/) seems to support several browsers, as does [SiteBar](http://sitebar.org/features.php).

Comment: @mcandre I emailed LastPass last month who own Xmarks to please include Opera, as they provide bookmark sync for the other major browsers, and they replied by saying they will take my enquiry into consideration